# Tableau Grouped Stacked Bar Charts

Tags: bar-chart, tableau-api, stackedbarseries

I'm working with some multi-year, multi-category data, multi department data. So I've created stacked bar charts for each year where the bars are the department and the stack is the category. Like so:

[image: Stacked bar charts]

However I cannot for the life of me figure out how to put each department next to each other and show multiple years side by side. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My data looks something like this:

```
 Category, Dept, 12_13, 13_14;
 1       , A   , 10   , 20   ;
 2       , A   , 22   , 1    ;
 1       , B   , 5    , 32   ;
 2       , B   , 34   , 7    ;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish. So in the chart above, you have departments in the rows, and the categories are represented by color? Is that correct? Could you clarify/rephrase how you'd like to change the chart?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your department Dimension and set the defaul sort as desired. I think that might solve what you're trying to do.

http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/en-us/help.htm#datafields_fieldproperties_sort.html